# beaglebone GPIO3_13 (aka GPIO109) not exposed on P8 or P9?

Tags: beagleboneblack

I have run into some problem controlling usb1' power.  as I investigated from
"https://e2e.ti.com/support/arm/sitara_arm/f/791/t/270060" It tells me that GPIO3_13 controls usb1_drvvbus pin, which controls the usb power.

I understand that there is software method to change the voltage of this pin. 
My question is that where is GPIO3_13 located on P8 or P9 expansion bays? I cannot find it on any diagrams.  Is it purposefully not exposed anywhere?

Comment: Why WOULD that pin be available on the expansion ports?  You couldn't use it for anything without killing the onboard USB port.

Comment: Thanks.  That is what I suppose, but not very sure about.

Answer (score 0):

You can control USB1 power from software on the beaglebone, if you are using a recent elinux.org Debian image (the necessary device tree overlay was merged in June 2015).  This uses a hack to expose the `usb1_drvvbus` signal as a fake LED, which can then be controlled using the files in `/sys`.

Firstly, load the dev-USB-PWR-CTL-00A1.dtbo device tree overlay.  For recent setups (where all dtbos are loaded by uboot and then passed to the kernel at boot time), this could be done by adding `dtb_overlay=/lib/firmware/dev-USB-PWR-CTL-00A1.dtbo` to `/boot/uEnv.txt` and rebooting (older kernels/uboots will need to use the older config mechanisms as described in `/boot/uEnv.txt`).

You can then do this:

```
echo 'usb1' > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
echo 0 > /sys/devices/platform/leds/leds/usb_hub_power/brightness
sleep 1
echo 255 > /sys/devices/platform/leds/leds/usb_hub_power/brightness
echo 'usb1' > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind
```