# Using GPIO3_13 (GPIO109) to disable USB VBUS

Tags: beagleboneblack

I found `dev-USB-PWR-CTL-00A1.dtbo` file. (I think [this is source code](https://github.com/beagleboard/bb.org-overlays/blob/master/src/arm/dev-USB-PWR-CTL-00A1.dts) for it).

Using this file I try to expose USB1_DRVVBUS pin as GPIO (GPIO3_13) with commands:

```
echo dev-USB-PWR-CTL > /sys/devices/platform/bone_capemgr/slots
echo 109 > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio109/direction
```

I see new cape entry in `slots` and new `gpio` files tree.

But when I change value with command

```
echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio109/value
```

I see new value in this file but nothing happens with USB VBUS.

What am I missing?

(Before you ask do I *really* need this: let's leave the consequences on the side for a moment.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this? [question about exactly this on the Beagleboard Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/beagleboard/lq1Y4diK3NQ)

Please note that there are some differences to back then and current images, e.g. by default CapeManager is disabled and [overlays are loaded once in U-Boot](https://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack_Debian#U-Boot_Overlays)

Comment: Yes. That's why I was looking for dtbo in kernel version 4.4. I saw also this unaswered question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45783004/]. Cape Manager seems to work fine - I can enable UART2 or CAN.

Comment: Did you disengage the USB port first? `echo '2-1' | tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind` (according to that post)

Comment: One notable difference is in the 'mode': `0x07` vs `0x0f` - I've looked it up and it seems that the former has pull-down enabled and the one you are using hasn't. Might make sense to recompile that dtso with mode 0x07 and try that. Or can you set the pull-down state from userspace?

Comment: Yes, I know, it's an output, it shouldn't matter with pull-up/down… Probably it's something else that we're missing.

Comment: Currently I don't have solution but I can add something about user TBR wrote above for other readers.
First thing - pin mode value `0x07` vs `0x0xf`.
Both values mean `mode=mux7 (GPIO)` and `pull type=pulldown`.
The difference is `pull=enabled` vs `pull=disabled`.
On Beagle Bone Back schematic (sheet 4): power distribution switch enable signal has 10k pulldown resistor.
So I have tried with solution from Google Group - changing mode value didn't work for me. [to be continued]

Comment: [cont.] Second thing - unbinding and binding USB port with `'2-1'`. This works fine when USB enumeration has been done correctly. In other case the last chance for USB device is to turn off USB bus power for a while. (In kernel 4.4 I tried `'1-1'` for root hub.)

Comment: you should unbind before you turn of VBUS. That's what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a recent elinux.org Debian image (the necessary device tree overlay was merged in June 2015), it includes a device tree overlay (with the comment "Unless you know what you are doing, do not load this cape!!!").  This uses a hack to expose the `usb1_drvvbus` signal as a fictitious LED, which can then be controlled using the led interface in `/sys`.

Firstly, load the dev-USB-PWR-CTL-00A1.dtbo device tree overlay.  For recent setups (where all dtbos are loaded by uboot and then passed to the kernel at boot time), this could be done by adding `dtb_overlay=/lib/firmware/dev-USB-PWR-CTL-00A1.dtbo` to `/boot/uEnv.txt` and rebooting (older kernels/uboots will need to use the older config mechanisms as described in `/boot/uEnv.txt`).

You can then do this:

```
echo 'usb1' > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
echo 0 > /sys/devices/platform/leds/leds/usb_hub_power/brightness
sleep 1
echo 255 > /sys/devices/platform/leds/leds/usb_hub_power/brightness
echo 'usb1' > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind
```

... to power-cycle the device attached to USB1.

Comment: Can you provide the URL of the repository for the Texas 4.4 kernel that you mentioned?

Comment: I didn't mention a Texas 4.4 kernel?  The above works on 4.9.x and 4.14.x mainline kernels.  It probably works on earlier 4.4 kernels as well - https://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack_Debian#Kernel_Options